# Will null iterators cause undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, iterator

```
using namespace std;
class myList
{
  public:
    mylist():_internalList(),_lastPostition(0)
  {
  }
    typedef list<string>::iterator Itr;
    bool enqueue(string);
    Itr next()
    {
      if(_lastPostition == 0)
        _lastPostition = _internalList.begin();
      if(_lastPostition == _internalList.end())
        return (_lastPostition = 0);
      return _lastPostition++;
    }
  private:
    list<string> _internalList;
    Itr _lastPostition;
}
```

`enqueue` is not `push_back`, it inserts based on some custom logic. 
I can't use `std::set` and overload `operator <`, because my insertion logic isn't transitive - `( a < b && b < c)` does not imply `a < c`.

This works but I'm not sure if its an undefined behavior.
Is it safe to assign 0 to an iterator and check for 0 ?

Comment: Why can't you just use `end()` as null-value.

Comment: I want to differentiate between two states, the list is not yet traversed and traversing is complete. the code which uses this class will use something like `while( itr = mylist.next()){` to loop through the list. If I use end(), it will not be possible to loop through.

Comment: @balki: It seems the proper thing to do would be to implement a custom iterator class that has a special `null`-value. You should try to stick to the standard way of iterating over sequences, because otherwise you will needlessly confuse people that read your code.

Comment: Or use a `boost::optional<Itr>` instead of `Itr`.

Comment: I assume it would have to be `return (_lastPostition == 0);` ?

Comment: @MSalters No. I want to return value 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Is it safe to assign 0 to an iterator and check for 0 ?" No.

Comment: (While iterators are modeled after pointers, not all iterators are pointers (obviously) and as such the literal `0` has no special meaning as it does for pointers.)

Comment: I would say the why is: because iterators may have assignment operators or ctors in addition to the copying operators required by the standard, but whether they do or not and, if so, their meaning, is not defined by the standard. So even if it compiles, for all you know, `itr = 0;` might have the same effect as `itr = _internalList.end();`

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign 0 to an iterator, you have to use some other special value, like `end()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `next` as shown below, and should also provide `has_next()` to check whether there is next item in the list or not.

```
Itr next()
{
   if ( !has_next() )
       _lastPostition = _internalList.begin();
   return ++_lastPostition;
}
bool has_next() const
{
   Itr  temp = lastPostition;
   return (++temp== _internalList.end());
}
```

Note: the behaviour of `next()` is circular; that is, on reaching end, it returns begin again!